# Sort IENumerable after DateTime

Tags: c#, sorting, ienumerable

I have the following

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WorldNews.xml");
        var feedXml = XDocument.Load(path);


        IEnumerable<NewsItem> feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("item")
                    select new NewsItem
                    {
                        Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
                        Link = feed.Element("link").Value,
                        Description = Regex.Match(feed.Element("description").Value, @"^.{1,180}\b(?<!\s)").Value,
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(feed.Element("pubDate").Value)

                    };
```

How can I sort this after "Date"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `let` to store the converted dates.

```
IEnumerable<NewsItem> feeds = 
    from feed in feedXml.Descendants("item")
    let date = Convert.ToDateTime(feed.Element("pubDate").Value)
    orderby date
    select new NewsItem
    {
        Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
        Link = feed.Element("link").Value,
        Description = Regex.Match(feed.Element("description").Value, @"^.{1,180}\b(?<!\s)").Value,
        Date = date
    };
```

To sort it after creating, you can do this.

```
feeds = feeds.OrderBy(f => f.Link).ToArray();
```

The reason I added `.ToArray()` is that without it, you'll be instantiating a chain of queries, each of which gets more and more expensive to calculate, and goes back to xml parsing each time.

Comment: I'd really like to sort it after defining. Because I waant to be ablte to sort after other parameters as well.

Comment: @SimonSondrupKristensen: I added some info about that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another noob question here: How can I sort this the opposite way: feeds = feeds.OrderBy(f => f.Date).ToArray();  ?

Comment: @SimonSondrupKristensen: `.OrderByDescending()`